# How can I make dynamic buttons from another class?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, button, dynamic

I'm trying to organize my project and I faced a problem that I can't add a button dynamically to the `MainForm`. How can I do that without getting errors and still making `MainForm` to launch first and not other class?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class anotherClass   
{
  public void AddButton(Form form)
  {
    Button b = new Button() { Text = "Dynamic Button", Width = 200 };
    form.Controls.Add(b);
  }
}

public class MyForm
{
 anotherClass obj = new anotherClass();
 obj.AddButton(this);
}
```

Comment: so what i need to put when I'm calling the class in the arguments?

Comment: nevermind just did it in main and now i dont want to redo it thx anyways

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = new Button() { Text = "Dynamic Button", Width = 200 };
        this.Controls.Add(b);
    }
```

Comment: Actually I know how to make that but i want it from another class!!! thats the point i was struggling with i know already how to create a dynamic button from the main class but not from another